# Triggering notification screen locked

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

In my Swift iOS app, I am able to capture that a notification was received, when either the app is running, or when the user gets a notification and clicks on the notification after receiving it.

But if the user received the notification when outside the app and clicks on the app icon on the home screen instead of clicking on the notification badge, the application does not detect that a notification was received. How do I get this to work?

Inside of my app delegate:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
}

if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. The whole point is that there are supposed to be different things that happen if the user clicks on the notification versus not clicking on it. It would be unexpected behavior for the user if they were purposefully ignoring a notification but then clicked on the app icon and then the app acted on the notification anyways. Imagine trying to ignore a message in the Messages.app by not clicking on the notification, but then you wouldn't be able to open the app otherwise because it would act on the notification.

Answer (score 1):

In the didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate you could save a value that the notification was received, and then on applicationWillEnterForeground you could inspect that value and act accordingly.